# How to reset all manually overriden permissions for a flatpak?

Tags: flatpak

Let's say I've used [`flatpak override`](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-override) to add/change some permissions and now I (regret it) and want to restore/reset them.
**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## CLI

It is a very good idea to first have a look at what you've changed.

For a specific app:

```
flatpak override --show my.app.id
```

For all apps:

```
flatpak override --show
```

Reset permissions for a single app:

```
flatpak override --reset my.app.id
```

Reset the global overrides:

```
flatpak override --reset
```

## GUI

Since version [1.8.0](https://blogs.gnome.org/tchx84/2022/05/31/flatseal-1-8-0/) the [Flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal) app supports modifying, displaying, and resetting global permissions.